# How to add Array to ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a global `ArrayList` `list` declared with the intention of adding a `float` variable to it in a method:

```
ArrayList<Float[]> list = new ArrayList<Float[]>();
```

Here is the method:

```
public void recieve(float[] coords)
{
    this.list.add(?); 
}
```

What is the syntax for adding `coords` to the `ArrayList`?

Comment: I cannot test this at the moment but I am reasonable certain your `coords` parameter will need to be converted to a `Float[]` (meaning an array of the object wrapper for a primitive `float`) before adding it to the `ArrayList`, since the `ArrayList` is expecting objects of type `Float[]`, not `float[]`. Other than that, you have it correct.

Comment: I am also not sure that the question is correct. You want to add a `float` variable, then pass in an array `float[]`.

Comment: One will need to change if you want to avoid extra conversion steps. Which one it is depends on external factors: are you using some library or framework that needs one or the other? Are you doing a lot of "real" math that would create a lot of extra boxing and unboxing, slowing things down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to convert it manually I think.

```
public void recieve(float[] coords) {
   this.list.add(convertToFloat(coords));
}

public Float[] convertToFloat(float[] coords) {
  Float[] converted = new Float[coords.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
     converted[i] = Float.valueOf(coords[i]));
  }
  return converted;
}
```

Comment: Never use the primitive wrapper constructors: either use the `valueOf` factory methods or just use autoboxing which does the same thing.

Comment: ok i edit it, thanks for the suggestion. What is the reason for that? edit: Ok I just read the javadoc for it which explains it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for this:

```
public void receive(float[] coords) { // fixed misspelling in name
    Float[] fCoords = new Float[coords.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)
        fCoords[i] = coords[i];       // autoboxing takes place here
    this.list.add(fCoords); 
}
```

Because the `ArrayList` expects a `Float[]`, but you have a `float[]` as parameter (notice the difference in letter case!) a manual conversion is required before adding it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare Arraylist type as float array, I believe you can just use as

```
list.add(coords);
```

Cheers

Comment: This will not work because the `ArrayList` stores `Float[]` but the method accepts `float[]`. Each element will need to be converted.

Comment: Ah i didn't notice they are different type.. Why don't you make it to accept Float [] then ?

Comment: @REALFREE You're technically right, if the rest of the program is designed in such a way that they have the freedom to do that. But we just don't have enough information. They'd probably have to convert it at some point along they way anyways. I suppose they could overload the method too if they are so restricted, to handle either scenario.